# IF and ELSE condition in DB2 query to display output

Tags: security, db2

Is there a way to display output from a table based on 2 different condition? For example I have a table DEMO that has a field PERSONGROUP . There are some users who belong to this  PERSONGROUP If PERSONGROUP = A or B and if the logged in user is mapped to these persongroup then it should display ONLY those records from DEMO table. If the logged in user does not belong to the persongroup A or B then it should display all the records from DEMO table.

Data in DEMO table

```
 DEMOID    PERSONGROUP  USER
  100        A           TOM
  200        B           TOM
  300                    DAVID
  400                    PAUL
```

When TOM logs in then he should see 100 and 200 record only. When DAVID or PAUL logs in then they should see all the 4 records.  Below is the same query that I had used however it does not work for the else part.

```
select * from demo where (exists (select 1 from persongroupteam where persongroup = DEMO.persongroup and respparty = :user and persongroup in ('A','B'))
```

Comment: change `:user` to `SESSION_USER`

Comment: What's the contents of the `persongroupteam` table in your select statement? How do you check which groups a user belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options in Db2:

- [SESSION_USER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011134.html) is a special register which allows you to write queries against the logged in user.
- Such a query could be the foundation for a VIEW.
- You can use SESSION_USER in rules based on [Row and Column Access Control (RCAC)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0057423.html). RCAC gives higher security than views.

In SQL you can use a CASE statement to implement IF / ELSE. Also see, e.g., this [example on how SESSION_USER is used to implement a row access rule](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0057468.html).

Comment: no it doesn't work. The issue is not with :user however its with the condition that needs to be written. I'm not sure how to achieve this using IF/ELSE.

Comment: See my answer and use CASE to implement IF/ELSE